# Getting "cross origin requests are only supported for http" error after login in salesforce based cordova hybrid ios app

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, cordova

### **Project configuration**

**Salesforce mobile SDK Cordova plugin version: 8.2.0.

Cordova ios: 5.1.1.

Type of application: Local**.

After login, I am getting below error.

cross origin requests are only supported for http
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.....html due to access control checks

[image: Cross error]

Please help me to resolve the issue.
Aslo I tried cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr but still, I am getting the error.

As per **Cordova-ios 6.0.0** official release note, they mention bellow point

_**Moved WKWebView support into Cordova-iOS and removed UIWebView code
Due to this change, the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin is obsolete and will not work with this release. If you have this plugin installed, it is safe to remove with Cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.

Additionaly, WKURLSchemeHandler support has been introduced with this release. **Using a custom scheme to serve your app content through fixes CORS issues that exist because of the strict security policies that WKWebView has applied to the file scheme. You can easily configure your Cordova project to use a custom scheme by setting the preference options scheme and hostname in the config.xml file.****_

So, If this is the solution then please can you provide the new salesforce mobile SDK Cordova plugin which supports **Cordova ios 6.0.0**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Cordova-ios 6.0.0 or 6.1.0 and install following plugin from github

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...but the latest salesforce mobile SDK (8.2.0)only supports cordova-IOS 5.1.1. Can you suggest me how to use Cordova-ios 6.0.0 or 6.1.0 over salesforce mobile SDK.

Comment: I have added an instruction below to solve this problem for Cordova-ios:5.1.1. Let me know if this helps solve your problem.

Comment: I already tried those steps but still getting the same error .please let me know if anything else I have to do apart from those steps.

Comment: I don't use Salesforce mobile SDK Cordova plugin. 
For me fixed "cross origin requests are only supported for http XMLHttpReques" error in other cases

Comment: ok..please can you tell me how you load the HTML file. In my case, I am using angular js (1.6) Router to load the file

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova-ios 5.1.1 you need to install 2 following plugins

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git#master
cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

and

you need to add   following to your config.xml file

```
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% working for me. Thanks

For Cordova-ios 5.1.1 you need to install 2 following plugins

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git#master
cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
and

you need to add following to your config.xml file

```
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```